# Как решаются подобные задачи

Tags: php

Привет дали выполнить тестовое задание и стало интересно как выполняются такие задачи, мне интересно какие библиотеки для этого требуются и сам принцип работы так как обычный цикл как понял тут не прокатит, дальше разберусь). Спасибо.

Требуется написать на PHP простую систему обработки клиентских заявок.
Необходимо обработать 10 000 заявок не дольше чем за 10 минут.

**Процесс обработки одной заявки:**
Обработчик засыпает на 2 секунды (эмулируем тяжелую операцию)
Добавляет запись в файл logger.txt об успешной обработке в формате:
lead_id, lead_category,current_datetime

Если обработка заявок определенной категории невозможна, остальные должны обрабатываться беспрепятственно.

Нельзя использовать PHP-фреймворки
Допускается использование подключаемых библиотек.

Comment: принцип - распараллеливание

Comment: получается на каждую итерацию создавать свой поток записи?

Comment: нет, 10 000 процессов - это будет неразумное решение

Comment: а как правильно ?

Comment: я же написал - распараллеливание

Comment: 10k за 10мин и пауза 2сек, посчитайте уж сколько минимум надо потоков

Comment: я бы брал чанками, и паралелил процесс, если уж так сильно надо.